# Install eawpatches midi soundfont alternative to freepats via apt

Tags: apt, software-installation, midi

I tried to install `eawpatches` like described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Midi/SoftwareSynthesisHowTo

But it seems the installation is outdated, I tried adding

```
deb https://www.fbriere.net/debian stable misc
```

to a new file in

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/midi-fbriere.net.list
```

But I get this error on `apt update`

```
 Get:24 https://www.fbriere.net/debian stable InRelease [8604 B]                            
 Err:24 https://www.fbriere.net/debian stable InRelease                                     
 The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E5C626294C4644D
```

Where do I get the key and why does it not load https://www.fbriere.net/debian which seems fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forget to add GPG key, follow [guide from repository site](https://www.fbriere.net/debian/) (accessed by mentioned link `https://www.fbriere.net/debian`):

> **Using the fbriere.net-keyring package (recommended)**
> ...
> This package can also be [downloaded](https://www.fbriere.net/debian/fbriere.net-keyring.deb), and installed with `dpkg -i`.
>
> **Manual installation**
>
> It is also possible to manually download the key, either from a keyserver or directly from this site, and add it via `apt-key`. Here are two examples:
>
> ```
>  wget -q -O- 'https://www.fbriere.net/public_key.html' | sudo apt-key add -
>  wget -q -O- 'http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x96B4BF71E4D7FB01' | sudo apt-key add -
> ```

then you can proceed with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and package installation.

Comment: great, that worked, How could I have found out the right link to the key myself?

Comment: I have simply visited the `https://www.fbriere.net/debian` page from web-browser and got instruction :)

Comment: I got it installed, but it doesn_t seem to work out of the box as described in the howto. my followup question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130431/enable-eawpatches-midi-soundfont-alternative-to-freep