# Enable eawpatches midi soundfont as alternative to freepats

Tags: 18.04, sound, midi

I installed ewapatches like:

```
sudo su
echo "deb https://www.fbriere.net/debian stable misc" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/midi-fbriere.net.list
wget -q -O- 'https://www.fbriere.net/public_key.html' | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q -O- 'http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x96B4BF71E4D7FB01' | sudo apt-key add -
apt install eawpatches-package
```

and followed the instruction on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Midi/SoftwareSynthesisHowTo

But it seems there is no such file `/etc/timidity/eawpatches.cfg`, only `/usr/share/eawpatches-package/eawpatches.cfg` but neither file work, if I add it to my timidity config

I get this error:

```
gravis.cfg: No such file or directory
gsdrums.cfg: No such file or directory
gssfx.cfg: No such file or directory
xgmap2.cfg: No such file or directory
timidity: Error reading configuration file.
Please check /etc/timidity/timidity.cfg
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used this software, but empirically I got the following steps:

1. run `make-eawpatches-package` script from `eawpatches-package` package (it will download the patches package and create deb-package named `eawpatches_12-10+local_all.deb`)
2. install deb-package with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ./eawpatches_12-10+local_all.deb
   ```

As the result you will have the cfg-files installed:

> ```
> $ dpkg -L eawpatches | grep /etc
> /etc
> /etc/timidity
> /etc/timidity/eawpatches
> /etc/timidity/eawpatches/default.cfg
> /etc/timidity/eawpatches/gravis.cfg
> /etc/timidity/eawpatches/gsdrums.cfg
> /etc/timidity/eawpatches/gssfx.cfg
> /etc/timidity/eawpatches/mt-32.cfg
> /etc/timidity/eawpatches/proteus2.cfg
> /etc/timidity/eawpatches/sndfont.cfg
> /etc/timidity/eawpatches/sustain.cfg
> /etc/timidity/eawpatches/xgmap2.cfg
> /etc/timidity/eawpatches.cfg
> ```

along with `*.pat` files inside `/usr/share/midi/eawpatches/*`.

---

This method is documented in `/usr/share/doc/eawpatches-package/README.Debian` and in `/usr/share/eawpatches-package/README.Debian`.